# Running a Rails app unit tests programatically through a Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, terminal

I am writing a ruby script to programmatically run the unit tests in one of my Rails application.The Rails application has following files available at its root:

**.ruby-gemset** containing following:

```
  my_rails_app
```

**.ruby-version** containing following:

```
  2.1.2
```

which are added to use a specific version of Ruby and a separate gemset to be created for the application.

My first version of script looks like following

```
      APP_ROOT_DIR_PATH = "/home/jignesh/my_rails_app"
      UNIT_TEST_FILE_PATH_PREFIX = "test/unit"

      unit_tests_dir = Dir.new("#{APP_ROOT_DIR_PATH}/#{UNIT_TEST_FILE_PATH_PREFIX}")

      Dir.chdir(APP_ROOT_DIR_PATH) do
      puts "Present Working Directory: #{Dir.pwd}"

      unit_test_files = unit_tests_dir.entries.select { |file_name| file_name.end_with?(".rb") }.sort
      puts "Total Unit Test: #{unit_test_files.size}"

      unit_test_files.each do |file_name|
       unit_test_relative_file_path = "#{UNIT_TEST_FILE_PATH_PREFIX}/#{file_name}"

        puts "Running unit test: #{unit_test_relative_file_path}"

        unit_test_output = `ruby -Itest #{unit_test_relative_file_path}`

        puts "===========> Output <=========="

        puts unit_test_output

        puts "==============================="
       end
      end
```

However the above script is not running correctly because it asks to do a **bundle install** and uses the Ruby version **ruby-1.9.3-p194** instead of the one specified in the **.ruby-version** file which is 2.1.2.

Changing the directory **manually** on shell terminal causes the application to use the defined gemset and ruby version in **.ruby-gemset** and **.ruby-version** files and run the unit tests successfully, however doing the same thing programatically doesn't work.Can anybody help me in fixing the problem hampering the script to run?

Below is the list of Ruby versions I have available and listed using **rvm list** command
          rvm rubies

```
      =* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]
     ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ i686 ]
     ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ i686 ]
     ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ i686 ]
     ruby-1.9.3-rc1 [ i686 ]
     ruby-2.1.0 [ i686 ]
     ruby-2.1.1 [ i686 ]
     ruby-2.1.2 [ i686 ]

      # => - current
      # =* - current && default
      #  * - default
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using a rake task for that? Some small modification of the existing rake test task would be a nice place to start. What is your objective there ?

Comment: @Martin Thanks. I want to run the tests one by one and from the test output grep some text and prepare a report in a desired format.But there are a lot of tests so I though a standalone ruby script is fit for such task.Using a rake task is an alternative available but I would want to go with my proposed approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve a very common problem here. You may find the [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) (and [Guard-Test](https://github.com/guard/guard-test)) project interesting: it will listen for file system changes and run your tests automatically whenever something changes in your app directory. You don't even need to start the script yourself! This really helps with building a good habit of testing early and often.

Regarding your original question: when you have set up RVM properly, everything should work just fine with Guard.

Comment: Thanks for your response.As I mentioned in my question changing directory manually and then running test using the command: "ruby -Itest test/relative/path/here" it works fine.It is when I try to do the same thing from the ruby script which is causing problem.And my RVM is set-up properly else it would not work in case when I manually run the commands.